# ng serve An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module?

Tags: angular

i have an angular project , whene i execute "npm start" , i have this error,
can you help me , how i solve this issus?
Terminal :
$ npm start

> initappz@4.1.0 start
> ng serve

An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module 'D:\app\Admin\node_modules@angular\compiler\fesm2015\compiler.mjs' imported from D:\app\Admin\node_modules@angular\compiler-cli\bundles\index.js
See "C:\Users\afisam\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-K7qvLY\angular-errors.log" for further details.

i want solve this issus

Comment: did you run `npm install` before running the app? maybe you are missing that dependency

Comment: Get full error log from here: `C:\Users\afisam\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-K7qvLY\angular-errors.log`